# Can we apply security updates only to a persistent live system?

Tags: updates, live-usb, persistence

I  have created a Xubuntu 20.04 persistent live with guidus/mkusb on a usb 4gig and works fine. I also have installed 5 programs, synaptic package mgr, mkusb, and a few others without problems. Also i have created Debian 10 xfce persistent live on a 8 gig usb and also works fine but it is slower than Xubuntu. 
My question is can i apply security updates only?
I have disabled updates because i red to the following that may cause breaking the system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb (see upgrade mkusb).Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

### Security Updates in persistent live drives

If there is enough free space in the partition for persistence you can apply security updates (and with more free space even all updates, `sudo apt full-upgrade`).

I tested security updates right now in a fresh persistent live Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system in an SSD with 60 GB. The used size of the partition for persistence increased to 1.7 GiB according to `df -h`. (See the line for `/cow ... /`), 1.8 GB according to `df -H`.

So 'security updates'

- is definitely a bad idea in your 4GB drive,
- should work in your 8 GB drive,
- but I would recommend it only in drives with at least 16 GB.

You might be able to tweak the settings to avoid such huge security updates, but I don't know exactly how to do it, and it would reduce the security.

### Workaround 1: Installed system in a USB drive

If security is important for you, I would recommend an installed system, installed like into an internal drive, but into a fast USB 3 drive with at least 16 GB.

See the following links

- [Step-wise instructions for installed system in a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
- [Notes about speed (and size)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre#Notes_about_speed)

### Workaround 2: Switch to daily iso files of released LTS versions

You can switch to a [current daily iso file of a released LTS version](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/212246/downloads) (18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS ...). Before point release #5 there will be daily iso files, and these are rather stable for released LTS versions. So instead of security updates you can simply create new persistent live drives.

You can be almost 100% sure that you can re-use the content of the home directory, and if there are not too big modifications, you can reuse the system part of the whole partition for persistence. [Tools for backup are bundled with mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data), and you can use them for transfer of your persistent data to a new persistent live system.

#### zsyncing command line and shellscript

This command line:

```
zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/xubuntu/focal/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
```

should work for you with Xubuntu Focal Fossa alias Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

You might prefer a more general shellscript. It can be used with all desktop flavours and the developing version (now groovy) and the newest LTS version (now focal). It can be a bit tricky to identify the web address for zsyncing to a released LTS version, and the shellscript can help you.

The following shellscript can be run in your main computer is a subdirectory with the name of the flavour of Ubuntu (with lower case), so in your case, when you make it executable an put it in PATH,

```
cd some-path/xubuntu
getdaily focal
```

Shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

if [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
 version="$1"
 version="${1%%-*}"
else
 echo "Usage:   $0 <version-nickname>"
 echo "Example: $0 bionic"
 echo "Flavour selected automatically for this directory"
 exit
fi

flavour=$(pwd)
flavour=${flavour##*/}
echo -e "$inversvid    zsyncing $flavour $version ... $resetvid"

if [ "$flavour" == "ubuntu" ]
then
 flavour=
 currpend=pending
else
 flavour="${flavour}/"
 currpend=current
fi

if [ "$flavour" == "ubuntustudio/" ]
then
 desktop=dvd
 daily_dvd=dvd
else
  desktop=desktop
  daily_dvd=daily-live
fi
echo "first try:"
echo zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/"$flavour$daily_dvd"/"$currpend"/"$version"-"$desktop"-amd64.iso.zsync
     zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/"$flavour$daily_dvd"/"$currpend"/"$version"-"$desktop"-amd64.iso.zsync
if [ $? -ne 0 ] && [ "$flavour" != "ubuntustudio/" ]
then
 echo "second try:"
 echo zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/"$flavour$version/$daily_dvd"/"$currpend"/"$version"-"$desktop"-amd64.iso.zsync
      zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/"$flavour$version/$daily_dvd"/"$currpend"/"$version"-"$desktop"-amd64.iso.zsync
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 if [ $# -eq 1 ]
 then
  ls -l "$version"-"$desktop"-amd64.iso
  <<< "I am ready now" espeak
 fi
else
 <<< "something went wrong" tee /dev/stderr | espeak
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Very helpful topics. I feel i prefer the second solution. I will have a look to be sure i understand the procedure and come back here. But i have one more question. In my Xubuntu persistent live there is the possibility of creating users and i did so with admin account. I didn' t go further to enable a password fearing to be locked out. By contrary others say it' s not possible to create an account with a pass on persistent live. I wonder is this true?.

Comment: @DimitriKoutsouris, I have created a second user which needs a password in a persistent live system. I have made it able to use `sudo` by adding it to the sudo group (in the file `/etc/group`) and checked that it works with `sudo`. With such a user it is also possible to make it an SSH server (by installing `openssh-server`). After that I have removed the standard user xubuntu. But be aware that an intruder can always boot the drive live-only. If you want really good security, you should have an installed system with 'encrypted disk' alias LVM with LUKS encryption (in the USB drive).

Comment: Well, I will see the users issue later as it seems a bit complicated to me.
As about your workaround 2 above, i have read the topics and i find amazing to sync my iso that way.
But i have 3 point to clarify with you.
1.The following link refers  to ZsyncCdImage. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage
- How i do obtain the syncing process. If you can provide the workaround for manualy syncing it will be very helpful. 
- Can i sync it whenever i use my persistent drive ? let’ s say within 15 days and more or has to be done every day.? cont/d

Comment: 2. In the present drive which i have created, the iso 9660/ cdrom partition is full. So where the surplus data will be stored when syncing with a daily iso if there is not space ? Thank you

Comment: @DimitriKoutsouris, You can install the package 'zsync' and make a shellscript, where you use it (replacing the current date with the text `current` to make it general). But if you want to do this twice a month, it is **important to backup** the data too (before zsyncing) because sometimes there are too big differences in the installed packages in the versions for the content of the persistent partition to be compatible. -- I could edit the answer to add my shellscript for zsyncing the daily iso file, so tell me if you want that.

Comment: @DimitriKoutsouris, the iso 9660/ cdrom *file system* is full, but I designed dus-persistent to make the partition 5 % bigger than the iso file to provide space for small increases of the iso file size, if you want to clone it directly (manually from the iso file to partition #4). But with a backup you might as well create a fresh persistent live drive and restore the content of `/home` or the whole content of the partition for persistence (from the backup to the fresh persistent live drive).

Comment: I installed zsync package. Now i guess will enter this in terminal zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/utopic-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync and press enter. Is that simple or i miss something? Otherwise can you please edit for me? I may sync the iso twice a month or so not earlier. For now i have set the system which at the moment works fine. Thank you

Comment: `zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/xubuntu/focal/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync` should work for you, but you might prefer the more general shellscript in the answer.

Comment: I' m sorry not sure i understand what is 'more general shellscript in the answer' If it isn' t much trouble can you specify ? Thank you.

Comment: The shellscript can be used with all desktop flavours and the developing version (now groovy) and the newest LTS version (now focal). But the simple and direct solution for you is the one-liner (one line command) in the previous comment.

Comment: Very well. I will backup the home directory just in case something goes wrong and i will proceed as above. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Good luck @DimitriKoutsouris :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108027/discussion-between-dimitri-koutsouris-and-sudodus).